# 1st index tab are not selected after loading the page in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a seller list in which i have to implemtned the 1st index seller will be active 
but in the case its not working but the 1st index will be please tell m sir what's the wrong in my code?

```
<div class="profile-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-icons" role="tablist">
        <li class="width100 ng-cloak" style="margin:5px 0; z-index:999;" ng-repeat="seller in sellerDto | filter: filterSeller" class="width100 {{sellerDto[0].userTypeDto.keyId ? 'active':''}}"> 
            <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="w3-left-align" ng-click="filterSellerInAlbum(seller.userTypeDto.keyId)">
                <span>{{seller.personName}}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have key `.` on your keyboard?

Comment: i don't understand what are you saying?